# Confusion with pseudo code used in describing a function in Javascript

Tags: function, declaration, pseudocode

Only in Mozilla Dev. Network is a function declaration explained with the following pseudoCode:

```
function name([param,[, param,[..., param]]]) {
   [statements]
}
```

Is there any special significance or reason why the parameter list is represented as a nested list instead of just listing out the parameters  as can be seen in any other function declaration on the Web?

Why not just show the declaration simply like:

```
function name(param1, param2, paramN...,) {
   [statements]
}
```

Am I looking into this too much?  Or is it just the Mozilla way of explaining the declaration?

Comment: 1. Please format your question properly and according to standards. 2. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax shows when a parameter is *optional*